# loading Chart.js on a php page through an ajax call is not working

Tags: php, ajax, chart.js2

I have a simple ajax call that is loading a php page. I am using chart.js to build a bar chart based off dynamic MySQL data.

If I browse to this page directly it works fine. However, if i use the following code to load the page, the data on the page loads but the chart does not.

The Script i am using to call the ajaxtest.php page is in the index.php page:

```
    <script>
                function getProduct(str) {
                    if (str == "") {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                        return;
                    } else { 
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } else {
                            // code for IE6, IE5
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = ''; // Hide the image after the response from the server
                                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

                            }
                        };
                        document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = '<img src="imgs/loader.gif" />'; // Set here the image before sending request
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxTest.php?prod="+str,true);
                        xmlhttp.send();

                    }
                }
                </script>
```

In this file i have bootstrap.css loaded in the head section. At the bottom of the page i am loading jquery.js, bootstrap.js and some customizations.js files (in that order). If i remove these from the index.php page, it makes no difference and the chart still does not load.

On the ajaxtest.php page i have it also calling the same files in the same locations.

I thought this may be my issue, so when i removed them from my index.php page it still does not load.

I am stumped as to why it wont load when calling it through ajax but does when i hit it directly. I do not see any errors in firebug/developer tools.

Any thoughts at all would be appreciated.

Comment: The Problem is, that chart.js (any any other similar plugin) does it's magin once the (original) document ist loaded. What you need to do is make chart.js do the same again, once your dynamicly inserted html is rendered.

Comment: @jeff Any direction on how I would do that? Thanks!

Comment: you must have somewhere something like `var myChart = new Chart($("#myChart"), {...});`. This then has to be called _after_ '#myChart' is inserted into the DOM, so in `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: If you post more relevant code (result of `ajaxtest.php`, how you init a chart, ..) I could help more, now I can only guess.

Comment: @Jeff - i have my chart initialization at the bottom of the page after the div tag for #mychart. The weird part is, when i hit ajaxtest.php directly the page loads fine with chart.js initializing as expected. Let me throw the pages in pastebin or something and put a link for you to see. I am sure its something silly i am doing.

Comment: ajaxtest.php -> http://pastebin.com/P325fvKt . index.php -> http://pastebin.com/mEiwxdE0